# What does AO2 in the remarks of an ASOS/AWOS mean?

Tags: weather

I occasionally see `AO2` in the remarks of an automated weather report. What does the AO2 mean?

`METAR KSLC 280453Z 00000KT 10SM FEW042 SCT055 BKN080 04/02 A2981 RMK AO2 CIG 037 NW RNWY SLP087 T00440022`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `AO2` notation means the station is automated and has a precipitation
discriminator. `AO1` means automated but no precipitation discriminator. The precipitation discriminator will be able to sense the difference between rain and snow.

The METAR format is documented in the [Federal Meterological Handbook No. 1](https://www.icams-portal.gov/resources/ofcm/fmh/FMH1/fmh1_2019.pdf) in Chapter 12. This particular notation is:

> **Type of Automated Station (AO1 or AO2).** AO1 or AO2 shall be coded in all METAR/SPECI from automated stations. Automated stations without a precipitation discriminator shall be identified as **AO1**; automated station with a precipitation discriminator shall be identified as **AO2**.