# What does AO2A in the remarks of a METAR mean?

Tags: weather, metar, asos

I am familiar with AO2 in the METAR remarks as described in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17109/what-does-ao2-in-the-remarks-of-an-asos-awos-mean), which means the station is automated and has a precipitation discriminator.  I have noticed sometimes there is AO2A in the remarks now as in this METAR:

`KBAD 171406Z 17012KT 10SM OVC004 18/17 A3002 RMK AO2A SLP168`

How is AO2A different from AO2?  I assume it is probably some additional capability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> AO2 Automated station without manual augmentation
> AO2A Automated station **with** manual augmentation.

That means this is an automated station but some elements have been added manually.

---

> 15.13.4
> Supplementary remarks may be included in observations from US stations following the identifier group RMK.
> These data are intended as national interest only and are equivalent to Section 5 of FM 12 SYNOP.

> Observations
> from automated stations shall have one of the following contractions as the first entry following RMK:
> AO2 Automated station without manual augmentation;
> AO2A Automated station with manual augmentation.

Source [WMO Manual on codes](https://library.wmo.int/doc_num.php?explnum_id=5730).